# Error in TensorFlow 1.15.X Source Compile in Highwayhash package building

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, odroid, tensorflow1.15

I'm trying compiling Tensorflow 1.15 on `Odroid-XU4` and getted some error that seems not related and exclusive to my platform. I installed Tensorflow 1.13 by source compile successfully. But for TF1.15 I got some error which experienced when use TF1.15.0 and TF1.15.1 and TF1.15.3.

My command to build using Bazel 0.26.1 is:

```
bazel --output_base=/media/odroid/.../CacheFolder build --config=opt             --config=monolithic --config=noaws            --jobs 1    --define=grpc_no_ares=true        --local_resources 1536,0.5,1.0            tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so        --discard_analysis_cache
```

After getting error for package "@io_rules_docker" which fixed by adding manually in WORKSPACEFILE and some same error I got this error:

```
>no such package '@highwayhash//': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config:platformlib'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If this Q is still of any interest to you can you please edit the build line (`azel --output_base=/media/odroid....` so it wraps across 3-4 lines, rather than having to scroll far to the right, and encountering big gaps of spaces? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: AND do you really need TF 1.15* ? Can't you get your project to work with 1.13? ;-( Sorry, and good luck.

Comment: I Solved this Error by downloading packages manually and running a local server and change url addresses to my localserver. @shellter